# Maxima not evaluating trig expressions

Tags: maxima

How do you make maxima give you the numerical value for a expression involving trigonometric function?

For example `''(sin(pi/6));` or `ev(sin(pi/6))` just returns `sin(pi/6)` instead of `0.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that 3.14... is written as `%pi` in Maxima (note the percent sign). Second, you can force numerical evaluation by writing `float(sin(%pi/6))` or `ev(sin(%pi/6), numer)` or, in the interactive console, `sin(%pi/6), numer`.